# jquery bxslider how to change text dynamically

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I want to use jquery bxslider on a webpage, and what I want is something like shown in the example: http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

the difference is I have some text elsewhere (beneath the slider content), and I want the content to change with each slider. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want the text to appear in: `<div id="img_caption"></div>` underneath the image:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: false,
  onSlideBefore: function($e) {
    var cap = $e.attr('title');
    $('#img_caption').html(cap);
  };
});
```

This is just a really good guess based on the documentation for bxSlider. It should be darn close, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it sorts of work, but there are two problems. 1- the first image and text doesn't synch. I mean it starts working from the second image and on-wards but the first image's text isnt displayed. 2 - the timing of the image and the text isnt synched. I  mean the text appears a few seconds after the image loads. Is there a way to fix those? Appreciate some feedback